# Editing multiple lines in VIM with variable indent

Tags: vim

I need to edid multiple lines at once. I know how to do it from the begining of the line with `ctrl+v` - `down ...` - `shift+i`, but the problem is that my variables are of different length, so I can't do the same trick to addit the end of each variable. I can do `.` on each line of course, but I was wondering if there is a faster way to achevie the same result?

*EXAMPLE:*
I need to change:

```
parser.add_argument('--name', type=str, help='The name of the experiment')
parser.add_argument('--debug', default=False, action='store_true', help=f'If the run is a debugging run')
parser.add_argument('--gpu_id', type=int, default=0 if torch.cuda.device_count() > 0 else -1, help='The ID of the GPU (if there is any) to run the network on (e.g., --gpu_id 1 will run the network on GPU #1 etc.)')
```

to:

```
name = 
debug = 
gpu_id =
```

So do do this I:

1. Go to the first line, hit `ctrl+v`, `down`, `down`, `down`, `shift+i`
2. Then delete everithing till the last `-`, then `esc`.
3. Edit the end of each line I can go to the end of the first line, `shift+c`, `space`, `=`.
4. Then on each other line repeat this by `f+'`, `.`

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

What I like to do in cases like that is the following:

1. Select all lines that you wish to edit in visual line mode (<kbd>V</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>)
2. Run a normal mode command on the selection by pressing <kbd>:</kbd>. That will automatically set the range to `'<,'>`, then type `norm yi'VpxxA =`.

So the whole command becomes `:'<,'>norm yi'VpxxA =`

That will yank the inner content of the first single quote pair in each line, replace the whole line by the yanked text, delete the first two characters and then append   `=`.

Answer (score 2):

With two simple substitutions (quicker than figuring out a single complex one):

```
" remove what comes before the variable name
:,+2s/.\{-}--

" substitute what comes after it with an equal sign
:'[,s/'.*/ =
```

See `:help :range`, `:help :s`, `:help pattern-multi-items`.

There are so many ways to do this…